# Duplicated $(info) Calls

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a makefile that displays a couple of information to the user using `$(info)` function calls. However, the makefile also includes auto-generated dependency files updated via `gcc -M`. Whenever such a dependency needs to be remade, GNU Make reparses everything again, thus duplicating the output generated with `$(info)` and similar calls.

Is there a way to determine whether GNU Make is performing the first or the second such pass in a makefile, in order to avoid duplication of `$(info)` lines?

Comment: Sounds like you are generating dependencies before compiling, which is really unnecessary. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7353426/automatic-header-dependencies-with-gmake/7358961#7358961

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just found it myself: the `MAKE_RESTARTS` variable is defined if GMake has restarted in the above circumstances. For example, the construct:

```
ifndef MAKE_RESTARTS
    $(info Hello!)
endif
```

will only display the forementioned message in the first such pass of Make.