# GNU makefile detect header changes

Tags: gnu-make

I have a directory with dozens of source and header files.  Is there a better or cleaner way than the following `%.o` target for `make` to detect changes to header files?  When the object is compiled, g++ is invoked with both the `.cc` and `.h` files which doesn't seem right, it should find the `.h` file automatically.

```
%.o: %.cc %.h
    g++ -c $^

OBJECTS=headless-driver.o config.o simplefm2.o emulator.o basis-util.o objective.o weighted-objectives.o motifs.o util.o

learnfun : $(OBJECTS) learnfun.o
    g++ $^ -o $@
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automatic header dependencies with gmake](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7353426/automatic-header-dependencies-with-gmake)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `%.o: %.cc %.h`
>
> `g++ -c $^`

You are specifying `$^` which expands to all dependencies. If you just want the first dependency on the Gcc command line, use `$<` instead.

Comment: It does not take into account dependencies introduced by `#include` directive.

Comment: Certainly true. There are separate tools for generating header file dependencies you can `include` ([`makedepend`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makedepend) et al.) if you have deep header relationships.