# Include headers in MakeFile

Tags: c++, makefile, header-files

I am trying to include my header files in the makefile so I don't have to `make clean && make` everytime I edit a header file that does not have a corresponding cpp file.

**EDIT**

So far I have this:

```
# Declaration of variables
CC = g++
CC_FLAGS = -Wall -g 

# File names
EXEC = Main
DEPS = MoveLogic.hpp
SOURCES = $(wildcard *.cpp) $(wildcard Pieces/*.cpp)
TARGET = $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o) 
TARGET_DEPS = $(DEPS:.hpp=.o) 

# Main target
$(EXEC): $(TARGET) $(TARGET_DEPS)
    $(CC) $(TARGET) $(TARGET_DEPS) -o $(EXEC)

# To obtain dependanies
%.o: %.hpp
    $(CC) $(DEPS) -o $@

# To obtain object files
%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) -c $(CC_FLAGS) $< -o $@

# To remove generated files
clean:
    rm -f $(EXEC) $(TEST) $(TARGET)
```

But I am getting the error

```
 ignoring file MoveLogic.o, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x43 0x50 0x43 0x48 0x01 0x0C 0x00 0x00 0x27 0x08 0x00 0x00 0x0B 0x02 0x68 0x42 ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): MoveLogic.o
```

Comment: What you are looking for is dependency generation. The GCC -MM or -MT switch is the start of your solution. Look for related SO questions. [makefile dependency](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2547/makefile-dependency-generation)

Comment: @KeithSmith I am still totally confused

Comment: How did you used the `DEPS` variable?

Comment: @Matthias well so far I am adding it to `SOURCES = ... $(DEPS)` ... but Im getting `clang: error: cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files` so I haven't got any futher

Comment: I usually put dependencies manually in order to compile only what is needed (but it is a maintainability mess): `foo.cpp: foo.h bar.h baz.h`

Comment: Header dependencies should be generated automatically, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/7358961/412080

Comment: Please see the update question, that is what I have so far - from looking at the suggested links

Comment: It looks like you are getting a linker error.  You should post full build output and talk about what architecture you are compiling for and what utilities are on your path.

Answer (score 0):

You must not add the headers to the `SOURCE` variable: All elements that are not `.cpp`  files go directly into `TARGET` that will be cleaned.

If the header names correspond to the source names you may use:

```
# To obtain object files
%.o: %.cpp %.h
    $(CC) -c $(CC_FLAGS) $< -o $@
```

However, then you will miss general header files. The best approach is to use auto debendencies as KeithSmith suggests.

Comment: This still does not work if I make it and then make a change to foo.hpp (in this example) when I rerun make it doesn't take into account the changes in foo.hpp

Comment: Sorry to bother you can you please explain how the autodependancies work

Comment: See the answer by pmod in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7353426/automatic-header-dependencies-with-gmake/7358961#7358961).

Comment: Please see the update question, that is what I have so far - from looking at the suggested links

Comment: You are trying to compile a header file only (i.e. `gcc -Wall -g MoveLogic.h`) since your are using the auto variable `$<`. Use one rule only.

Comment: Now it is quite a mess. You need a rule to generate dependencies. Check the [make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-g_t_0040code_007b_002dMM_007d-_0028to-GNU-compiler_0029-286), Section 4.14.