# Make rebuilds files included with -include

Tags: makefile

I have a very complicated makefile which I am not going to include here for obvious reasons.  I have rules to build dependency files and then include them with lines along the lines of '-include myobj.d'.

I also (obviously) have a rule to build a *.d file.

I then have rules along the lines of

```
.PHONY: clean
clean:
      rm myobj.d myobj.o ...
```

When I do make clean, first it rebuilds all the .d files before deleting them.  I ran make with -d and examined the debug information and it is trying to rebuild all the files I include with "-include" before examining the targets it was told to build.  I have a whole pile of "rules.mk" for building different code units and it tries to rebuild all of those too.

This wouldn't be a problem, except that the .d files that are being included actually do have rules to build them.  When I say "make clean" I want make to just execute the clean rule, not rebuild all the stupid dependency files just so I can delete them...

This is particularly problematic if the build is in a weird state where half the code is built and the rest isn't and I am trying to do a make clean to get back to a good state.

How do I tell make to not try to automatically rebuild an included file?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need rules for `.d` files these days, this is a common misconception. See [Automatic header dependencies with gmake](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7358961/412080) for more details.