# how to force recompile when changing Makefile flags?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++

I am compiling some project with dependency so i won't have to recompile each time, but when i am adding -Dsome_flags to my CFLAGS, it is not recompiling.

```
dep: $(CPPS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -M $(CPPS) > dep
```

i add to my CFLAS -DDEBUG_FLAG and it forces me to do make clean and make instead of make.

Comment: You modify the makefile, and it does not recompile?

Comment: You may not need a dependency generator rule at all. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7358961/412080

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest, in my opinion, would be to do a `make clean` and then a `make`.  This is of course assuming that you want all source files to be recompiled due to the change in compiler flags.  But you seem to not like this method.

If you want to modify the makefile, you can add the name of your makefile to every rule for compiling source files, for example:

```
    somefile.o : somefile.cpp <makefile_name>
            $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) somefile.cpp -o somefile.o
```

or

```
    %.o : %.c <makefile_name> 
            $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) somefile.cpp -o somefile.o
```

Given the size of the project, and the number of rules involved, doing a `make clean; make` may be the easiest and fastest method.  However, as always, you mileage my vary.

Just my $0.02 worth, hope it helps 
T.

Comment: This is pretty much the method I've seen in practice.

Comment: This doesn't work if the flags changed due to command line changes. For example `make CFLAGS=-DDEBUG` won't recompile anything.

Comment: @KevinCox yea, you are correct.  However recall how make works,  It compares the last modified time stamp of each target against the last modified time stamp of all of that target dependencies.  If one of the dependencies have been modified after that target was last built, then the target is rebuilt.  If you modify a flag on the command line like you suggest, then there is not change to the file system and you do not get the desired recompilation.  In a case like this, the use of  `make clean` `make CFLAGS=-DDEBUG` should do the trick

Answer (score 6):

It won't recompile because you don't have the makefile itself listed as a dependency.

```
dep: $(CPPS) Makefile
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -M $(CPPS) > dep
```

That said, if you're feeding in make flags from the command line (e.g. `CFLAGS=-O3 make all`), `make` has no way of detecting that you've changed those and forcing a full build.

Comment: No way of overcoming the command line issue. `make` has no way to remember how it was last run. Also, you'll have to change `Makefile` to wherever your makefile is.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone the following question has the same set of issues when dealing with multiple targets and their dependencies? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30043480/make-recipe-to-prevent-rebuilding-of-non-dependent-targets#

Comment: @SamiKenjat That one is trying to prevent unneeded rebuilds. This one is trying to prevent *skipping* a needed rebuild.

Answer (score 2):

Makefile looks for changes based on the data it has. Your Makefile states the only dependencies are defined under **$(CPPS)**.

```
dep: $(CPPS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -M $(CPPS) > dep
```

So the make tracks the changes only within the given list, i.e., $(CPPS). So the resolution is:

```
dep: $(CPPS) Makefile
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -M $(CPPS) > dep
```

For complete but non-complex example, here is my Makefile for a helloworld program:

```
OBJS = helloworld.o
default: hw

%.o: %.c Makefile
    gcc -c $< -o $@

hw: $(OBJS)
    gcc $(OBJS) -o $@

clean:
    -rm -f $(OBJS) hw
```

Everytime I change my makefile it gets recompile! :)

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question while searching for an answer to this same problem, but decided I wanted the complete answer rather than "just depend on the Makefile", so here's a general implementation I cooked up.

Assume you start with a Makefile that looks something like this (I've added a BUILD_DIR variable and all/clean targets to flesh out the OPs example):

```
################
# Setup:

BUILD_DIR := build


################
# Basic targets:

all: dep $(CPPS)
    @echo "make all"        # E.g. some build commands...

clean:
    @echo "make clean"      # E.g. some cleanup commands
    @rm -rf "$(BUILD_DIR)"  # Etc. ...

dep: $(BUILD_DIR) $(BUILD_DIR)/dep

################
# Build details:

$(BUILD_DIR):
    mkdir -p "$(BUILD_DIR)"

$(BUILD_DIR)/dep: $(CPPS) Makefile
    echo $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -M $(CPPS) > "$(BUILD_DIR)/dep"

.PHONY: all clean dep
```

Now, you want to modify this Makefile so that it depends on any build options used, so you introduce a new, intermediate file in the "Setup" section (saved in the build directory, presumably along with all other build artifacts):

```
# Stores the last options used for compilation:
CC_OPT_FILE := $(BUILD_DIR)/cc_options
```

You need a way to invoke the "clean" target conditionally; I've opted to modify the "clean" recipe to move the cleanup code to a make variable for reusability (note: MAKE_CLEAN contains spaces, **NOT** tabs):

```
MAKE_CLEAN =                                            \
  echo "make clean"      # E.g. some cleanup commands   \
  rm -rf "$(BUILD_DIR)"  # Etc. ...
clean:
    @$(MAKE_CLEAN)
```

Now you add a section after "Basic targets", to save the options to a cc_options file, check if that intermediate artifact has changed, and force a clean build if so [note that you can include as many shell-variable options into this file as you want, e.g. $(CPPFLAGS), $(CXXFLAGS), $(LDFLAGS), etc.; also note, spaces, **NOT** tabs are used in this block]:

```
###########################################
# Do clean build if compile options change:

# Usage: $(call MK_CC_OPT_FILE,<outfile>)
MK_CC_OPT_FILE =                        \
  mkdir -p "$(dir $(1))" &&             \
  echo "$(CFLAGS)" > "$(1)" &&          \
  echo "$(INC)" >> "$(1)" # Etc. ...
ifeq ($(findstring clean, $(MAKECMDGOALS)),)    # "clean" target NOT requested?
  $(shell $(call MK_CC_OPT_FILE,$(CC_OPT_FILE).tmp))  # Make tmp options file
  ifeq ($(.SHELLSTATUS),0)    # Success?
    $(shell cmp --silent -- "$(CC_OPT_FILE)" "$(CC_OPT_FILE).tmp")
  endif
  ifneq ($(.SHELLSTATUS),0)   # Options differ (or couldn't write file/etc.)?
    $(warning ***** CC options changed: forcing clean target)
    _ := $(shell $(MAKE_CLEAN))     # [Note: dummy assignment is required here!]
    ifneq ($(.SHELLSTATUS),0)
      $(error MAKE_CLEAN failed)
    endif
  endif
endif
$(shell $(call MK_CC_OPT_FILE,$(CC_OPT_FILE)))  # Save curr opts for next time
```

That's it! Now any time any of the options used by your build commands change, the Makefile performs a clean make before continuing the build. The only requirement is that the CC_OPT_FILE includes any options flags your Makefile passes to the compiler or linker, which you can find in your other target recipes and add to MK_CC_OPT_FILE as needed.