# Rename .o files using Makefile and gcc

Tags: gcc, makefile, linker

I have several lines in Makefile that are compiling and producing `.o` and `.d` files. I want two sets of `.o` `.d` to be produced, something like:

```
name.d
name_hello.d
name.o
name_hello.o
```

Already found how to change names of `.d` using `"$(@:.o=_hello.d)"` but have no success changing .o Perhaps i need to play with `$@` but have no idea how to do it.

Here is Make file code:

```
$(OBJECT_DIRECTORY)/%.o: %.c
# Build header dependencies
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDEPATHS) -M $< -MF "$(@:.o=.d)" -MT $@
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDEPATHS) -M $< -MF "$(@:.o=_hello.d)" -MT $@
# Do the actual compilation
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDEPATHS) -c -o $@ $<
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDEPATHS) -c -o $@ $< - this line i want to change
```

I use `arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe` for ARMs and `make.exe`

---

Update

Seems that using separate target is preffered solution than changing names. So, i did separate target for it. But it is never used. In other place of the Makefile there is next line of code that tells compiler what `.o` files to use:

```
C_OBJECTS = $(addprefix $(OBJECT_DIRECTORY)/, $(C_SOURCE_FILENAMES:.c=.o) )
```

I suppose that i need to change it to something like:

```
C_OBJECTS_hello = $(addprefix $(OBJECT_DIRECTORY)/, $(C_SOURCE_FILENAMES:.c=*_hello.o) )
```

Please tell how to modify `C_OBJECTS` in order to make compiler use `*_hello.o` files

---

Update 2

This is how `C_OBJECTS` used, i suppose some kind of a filter in `C_OBJECTS` tells `CC` ( `arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe` ) to use certain `.o` files. And since `*_hello.o` files are not used in the filter they are also not produced in their target.

```
## Link C and assembler objects to an .out file
$(OUTPUT_BINARY_DIRECTORY)/$(OUTPUT_FILENAME).out: $(BUILD_DIRECTORIES) $(C_OBJECTS) $(ASSEMBLER_OBJECTS) $(LIBRARIES)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(C_OBJECTS) $(ASSEMBLER_OBJECTS) $(LIBRARIES) -o $(OUTPUT_BINARY_DIRECTORY)/$(OUTPUT_FILENAME).out
```

I know that this is written in make help and i am reading it, but still not able to find an answer

---

Update 3

Here is how i modified 'C_OBJECTS' , and seems this works:

```
C_OBJECTS_hello = $(addprefix $(OBJECT_DIRECTORY)/, $(C_SOURCE_FILENAMES:.c=_hello.o) )
```

Comment: _but have no success changing `.o`_ - changing it to what?

Comment: My objective is to have both *.o and *_hello.o files.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7358961/412080

Comment: You can certain create a `$(C_OBJECTS_hello)` variable, but _creating_ a variable doesn't mean it's then used later on. You should check where `C_OBJECTS` is now used, and consider the implications of  `$(C_OBJECTS_hello)`. We don't know how you use `$(C_OBJECTS)` or what's special about `_hello.o`, so that's about as far as our advice can go.

Comment: 'C_OBJECTS' are used by gcc, i described this in 'Update 2' . Thanks for your help @MSalters

Comment: @VladimirTsykunov: Fairly obvious, that: there's apparently a single output and all the `C_OBJECTS` are linked in. The `_hello` ones aren't linked in, so why build them if they're unused?

Comment: i want to have multiple .hex from one makefile and doing this step by step. First step was to have two sets of '.o .d'. Just now i created 'C_OBJECTS_hello'  and modified its arguments and this works, i have two sets of files. @MSalters

Comment: Well, one of the most simple solutions to that would be a rule `$(OUTPUT_FILENAME)_hello.out : $(OUTPUT_FILENAME).out <newline><tab>cp $(OUTPUT_FILENAME).out $(OUTPUT_FILENAME)_hello.out`. But presumably you want two _different_ outputs. And we don't know how they differ; if they indeed differ in `gcc` options then you indeed need two different sets of object files. Mind you, I would have used a separate build directory instead of a suffix (so I'd have `obj/foo.o` and `obj_hello/foo.o`)

Comment: They differ in include directories. I had an idea having two different folders, perhaps i will implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You indeed would use a replacement. The `$@` variable expands all the `%.o` matches. That's why you had a `$(@:.o=.d)` replacement; you needed a `.d` file for each `%.o` match.

In this case, you can indeed use a `$(@:.o=_hello.o)` replacement. Note that this is NOT a dependency of the `%.c` input; it is a secondary output.

The alternative is to add a second output `$(OBJECT_DIRECTORY)/%.o $(OBJECT_DIRECTORY)/%_hello.o: %.c`. In this case, you wouldn't use `$@` but use `$*` which is the matched `%`. So your two dependency files would be `$(OBJECT_DIRECTORY)/$*.d` and `$(OBJECT_DIRECTORY)/$*_hello.d`

Comment: It is not even a _secondary_ output, since make is not aware of it at all.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin: Right, should have listed it as an output.

Comment: Please look, i made update for the topic. Did separate target for the *_hello.o but the target is never used.

Comment: @VladimirTsykunov: Well, the rule tells `make` **how** to build `*_hello.o` but not **why**. Make doesn't execute random rules; it works back from the intended end goal(s) to figure out what intermediate files are required.

Answer (score 1):

Your makefile rule produces more files than `make` is aware of. `$(OBJECT_DIRECTORY)/%.o: %.c` says it builds one `.o` from `.c`, whereas you would like it to build 4 files.

You need to make `make` aware what files its rules produces, so that it can build a complete dependency graph:

```
$(OBJECT_DIRECTORY)/%.o $(OBJECT_DIRECTORY)/%.d: %.c # Compile and build dependencies.
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDEPATHS) -MD -MP $<

$(OBJECT_DIRECTORY)/%_hello.o $(OBJECT_DIRECTORY)/%_hello.d: %.c # Compile and build dependencies.
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDEPATHS) -MD -MP $<
```

Note that these rules do not explicitly name the `.d` output file, letting the compiler determine it by replacing `.o` with `.d`.

Now that you have two rules instead of one `make` can parallelize their execution when `-j` flag is used.

Note that you should not need explicit rules for auto-generated dependencies for the reasons stated in https://stackoverflow.com/a/7358961/412080.

Comment: Thanks this is useful, i did two targets that seems produce two sets of files as i need.